# Sympy tensorproduct and tensorcontraction

Tags: sympy

I want to do two computations with sympy and one substitution:

The first is: "E:E" or in index notation "E_{ij}E{ji}"

The second is: "T_{ijmn} T_{mnkl}"

After I do these calculations I would like to replace the symbols with numeric values.

I have the following code:

```
import sympy as sp
import numpy as np
sp.init_printing(pretty_print=False)


# e = sp.MatrixSymbol('e',3,3)
# E = sp.Matrix(e)
def foo():
    e = sp.MatrixSymbol('e',3,3)
    E = sp.Matrix(e)
    
    result1 = sp.tensorcontraction( sp.tensorproduct(E, E), (0, 2), (1,3))
    
    T = sp.tensorproduct(E, E)
    
    result2 = sp.tensorcontraction( sp.tensorproduct(T, T), (2,4), (3,5))
    
    return [result1, result2]

# Verification
res1, res2 = foo()

E_num = np.array([[1,2,3],
                 [4,5,6],
                 [7,8,12]])

res1 = res1.subs({ E[0,0]:E_num[0,0], E[0,1]:E_num[0,1], E[0,2]:E_num[0,2],
                   E[1,0]:E_num[1,0], E[1,1]:E_num[1,1], E[1,2]:E_num[1,2],
                   E[2,0]:E_num[2,0], E[2,1]:E_num[2,1], E[2,2]:E_num[2,2]})


res2 = res2.subs({ E[0,0]:E_num[0,0], E[0,1]:E_num[0,1], E[0,2]:E_num[0,2],
                   E[1,0]:E_num[1,0], E[1,1]:E_num[1,1], E[1,2]:E_num[1,2],
                   E[2,0]:E_num[2,0], E[2,1]:E_num[2,1], E[2,2]:E_num[2,2]})

check1 = np.einsum("ij,ji", E_num, E_num) - res1

T1 = np.einsum("ij,mn->ijmn", E_num, E_num)
T2 = np.einsum("mn,kl->mnkl", E_num, E_num)

check2 = np.einsum("ijmn,mnkl->ijkl", T1,T2) - res2
```

In the above code I cannot replace the `E` matrix with numerical values as the symbolic variable is defined inside the function. I can do it if I define them outside. Any way to look into the expression and get the symbols to replace?
Additionally, `check1` is not zero as it appears to be doing E_{ij}E_{ij}, whilst `check2` appears to be correct.  Am I not asking to contract the correct indices?

Best Regards

Comment: I questions like this I like to see some intermediate results.  Otherwise you'll have to wait till I can run the code on my computer see them myself.

Comment: Your `check1` `einsum` works with the `E_num` and `E_num.T` - elementwise multiplication followed by sum of all terms.  You want `np.einsum('ij,ij',E_num, E_num)`.  Your `result1` is just the sum of the elementwise square of `E`.

Comment: The docs say that for matrix multiplication the indices should be `(1, 2)`: https://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/tensor/array.html#products-and-contractions

Answer (score 0):

Your `res1` - before numeric substitute is

```
In [18]: res1
Out[18]: 
   2      2      2      2      2      2      2      2      2
e₀₀  + e₀₁  + e₀₂  + e₁₀  + e₁₁  + e₁₂  + e₂₀  + e₂₁  + e₂₂
```

That's the same as

```
np.einsum('ij,ij', E_num, E_num)
```

or

```
np.sum(E_num * E_num)
```

The `einsum` contraction of the array with its transpose:

```
In [18]: np.einsum("ij,ji", E_num, E_num)
Out[18]: 324
In [19]: np.einsum("ij,ij", E_num, E_num.T)
Out[19]: 324
```

Using `E.T` in your `res1` calcultion gets the same thing

```
In [24]: sp.tensorcontraction( sp.tensorproduct(E, E.T), (0, 2), (1,3))
Out[24]: 
   2                              2                  2
e₀₀  + 2⋅e₀₁⋅e₁₀ + 2⋅e₀₂⋅e₂₀ + e₁₁  + 2⋅e₁₂⋅e₂₁ + e₂₂ 

In [25]: _.subs({ E[0,0]:E_num[0,0], E[0,1]:E_num[0,1], E[0,2]:E_num[0,2],
    ...:                    E[1,0]:E_num[1,0], E[1,1]:E_num[1,1], E[1,2]:E_num[1,2],
    ...:                    E[2,0]:E_num[2,0], E[2,1]:E_num[2,1], E[2,2]:E_num[2,2]})

Out[25]: 324
```

I haven't read the docs for `tensorproduct` or `tensorcontraction`.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Agreed, but why isn't `tensorproduct( Matrix, Matrix )` doing matrix multiplication but element wise multiplication? I guess it would be very helpfull to have something similar to the `einsum` in numpy. I guess I need to be more careful with this. Additionally, any thing regarding a substitution if the symbolic variables are inside the function?

Comment: See what using `E.T` in your `res1` does.

Comment: Hi, in the `subs` section how did you get access to the variable if it is inside the function? This would be the main take for replacing the variables. One you get the variables from the function you will no longer have access to the `E`, you can get the `free_symbols` but from there I do not know how to replace the variable where the symbol `e` is present

Comment: In this interactive session, the previous result is available as the `_` variable.

Comment: Noted. But this will not allow to replace the symbolic Matrix once it comes out of the function as you will lose the access to `E` variable  (to the best of my knowledge)

Comment: `Out[24]` is a sympy expression, which has a `subs` method.

Comment: Yes. But if you put this in a script, after the execution of the `foo` method, the variable `E` is no longer in the scope ( but should be inside the return variables). The question is how to replace the symbolic matrix variable with values on the output of the function

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/247099/discussion-between-mysticsnake-and-hpaulj).

Comment: For use in a script, just change to `res1 = sp.tensorcontract ...`.  The only change I am making is using `E.T` in the `tensorproduct`.